# how to organize posts with pretty permalinks [wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

i did a lot of research, and find a lot of solution that almost solve my problem, but none of them works 100%.

the most critical part it's the permalinks
using custom posts nothing worked to make the permalinks rights.

it's not possible to use categories because you can't duplicate categories, even if is a child.
i tried add only taxonomies, i tried custom posts with custom taxonomies

i can have "product", "software" and "cad", because if you select several categories only one is shown on the link

I want something like that.
Create a post, and select the categories and the result will be like the list below

```
courses
|
|-cad
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/courses/cad/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/courses/cad/software-two
|   |-software three    mysite.com/courses/cad/software-three
|   
|-cae
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/courses/cae/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/courses/cae/software-two
|   |-software three    mysite.com/courses/cae/software-three
|
|-cam
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/courses/cam/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/courses/cam/software-two
|   |-software three    mysite.com/courses/cam/software-three

products
|
|-cad
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/products/cad/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/products/cad/software-two
|   |-software three    mysite.com/products/cad/software-three
|   
|-cae
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/products/cae/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/products/cae/software-two
|   |-software three    mysite.com/products/cae/software-three
|
|-cam
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/products/cam/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/products/cam/software-two
|   |-software three    mysite.com/products/cam/software-three

services
|
|-cad
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/services/cad/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/services/cad/software-one
|   |-software three    mysite.com/services/cad/software-one
|   
|-cae
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/services/cae/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/services/cae/software-one
|   |-software three    mysite.com/services/cae/software-one
|
|-cam
|   |
|   |-software one      mysite.com/services/cam/software-one
|   |-software two      mysite.com/services/cam/software-one
|   |-software three    mysite.com/services/cam/software-one
```

and i will have another links with more depth with repeated cotegories.
something like

```
mysite.com/product/cad/software-one/version-x
mysite.com/product/cad/software-one/version-y
mysite.com/product/cad/software-one/version-z
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up the right permalink structure. Go to `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` and select a custom permalink of the form `/%category%/%postname%/`, saving at the bottom.
2. Set up the right tag structure. Go to `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category` and create three tags:

   - `courses`
   - `products`
   - `services`

   Then create categories as children of those tags by selecting the appropriate parent tag from the dropdown:

   - `cad`
   - `cam`
   - etc.

When you create a post, select the innermost tag that is applicable, not the parent.

Your posts should now have the permalink `/courses/cad/software-one/` for example.

Comment: 1. already did that.
2. already did that.
And as i said you can have duplicated categories, on the second time wordpress will create "cad-products"